# Visibility of superclass constructor parameters in subclass constructor

Tags: python, oop

Consider this example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar: int, baz: str):
        self.bar = bar
        self.baz = baz


class SubFoo(Foo):
    def __init__(self, qux: float, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.qux = qux


some_sub_foo = SubFoo(1.0, 3, 'test')
other_sub_foo = SubFoo(bar=4, baz='hello', qux=42.0)  # or in whatever order
```

However, when writing a `SubFoo()` definition, editors and IDEs will only be able to provide type hints and auto-completion for the subclass' own parameters, the superclass' parameters are effectively hidden. (interestingly, CoPilot sees right through it, but that's not a solution to my question)

My question: is there some way, Pythonic or nasty, that would allow me to write SubFoo without having to repeat the full signature of `Foo` verbatim, while retaining autocompletion, type hints, etc.?

A solution that requires rewriting of `Foo` would be acceptable, but of course a solution that only requires work on `SubFoo` would make it more useful. And if there's some solution that would work for other methods, but not for constructors, I'd be interested to see it as well.

As for repeating the entire signature of `Foo` verbatim, this works and behaves as required, but is impractical when extending more complex classes:

```
class SubFoo(Foo):
    def __init__(self, qux: float, bar: int, baz: str):
        super().__init__(bar, baz)
        self.qux = qux
```

Note that I don't see objections to what I'm asking out of principle. Constructors like this break the Liskov substitution principle, but that typically doesn't apply to constructors anyway. If there's some other reason why nobody should want this in the first place, that might be a good answer as well.

Comment: Didn't you mean to call `super().__init__(bar, baz)` in your last `__init__`?

Comment: As far as I know, Python and the most popular Python IDEs don't have what you ask for built in.

Comment: Also in C++ and Java it's standard practice to manually repeat relevant superclass constructor arguments (including type and name) in the constructor. One reason for doing so is that the constructor arguments are part of the contract between the class and the user of the class creating instances. At instance creation time it doesn't matter whether some functionality is implemented using inheritance or composition (or both). It's the job of the constructor to take all arguments, and distribute them to constructors of inherited or composed classes.

Comment: What makes you believe that the Liskov substitution principle does not typically apply to constructors? It most certainly does.

Comment: The aim here is not to get into a discussion of the philosophy of computer science here, but the principle is "Let phi(x) be a property provable about objects x of type T. Then phi(y) should be true for objects y of type S where S is a subtype of T."  Since a constructor belongs to the class, and not to the object, it can be considered not to apply - any attribute or method on an instance of the subclasss should be interchangeable with the same on the instance of the superclass though. If you don't agree @blhsing, that's fine - that's besides the point of the question.

Comment: @Grismar My point is that, if you choose to follow the Liskov substitution principle, then the principle applies to all methods equally, including the constructor. The `__init__` method is not a class method for a reason. It takes arguments meant to be specific to the instance being instantiated and initializes its instance attributes accordingly, so the Liskov substitution principle applies. You're confusing `__init__` with `__new__`, which is indeed a class method and typically does not perform instance-specific initialization itself (but calls `__init__` after it's done).

Comment: Clearly splitting hairs; I'm sure you're aware that the process of object creation and initialisation in Python is split between `__new__` and `__init__` (which is then typically called the constructor), where most popular languages have constructors that combine the functions. In Python, `__new__` is rarely overwritten, while `__init__` is typically overriden by subclasses to introduce new object attributes. Even if you were to make the point that `__init__` could be called to reinitialise an object, the same argument with regard to LSP that applies to constructors more broadly, applies here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hack around a solution for it [using the inspect module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html), but I personally wouldn't do it. It's not necessary that the tools you're using will actually make use of such runtime modifications. IDEs do their own static code analysis to figure things out.

Again, this is just a demonstration, not a solution that covers all edge cases. One can have any type of logic before and around the `super()` call and you never know what exactly is being passed to the base classes.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from inspect import signature, Signature
from types import FunctionType


class AnnotatingMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        cls = super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace)
        for attr_name, attr in namespace.items():
            if isinstance(attr, FunctionType):
                parameters = OrderedDict(signature(attr).parameters)
                for base in bases:
                    if hasattr(base, attr_name):
                       parameters.update(signature(getattr(base, attr_name)).parameters)
                
                parameters = OrderedDict([(k, v) for k, v in parameters.items() if k not in {"args", "kwargs"}])
                attr.__signature__ = Signature(parameters.values())

        return cls


class Foo(metaclass=AnnotatingMeta):
    def __init__(self, bar: int, baz: str):
        self.bar = bar
        self.baz = baz

    def method(self, a: int, b: str, c: float):
        pass


class SubFoo(Foo):
    def __init__(self, qux: float, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.qux = qux

    def method(self, d: float, *args, **kwargs):
        super().method(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now if we check `help()` on the class and its methods:

```
>>> import pydoc

>>> print(pydoc.render_doc(SubFoo, "Help on %s"))
Help on class SubFoo in module __main__

class SubFoo(Foo)
 |  SubFoo(qux: float, bar: int, baz: str)
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      SubFoo
 |      Foo
 |      builtins.object
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self, qux: float, bar: int, baz: str)
 |      Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
 |  
 |  method(self, d: float, a: int, b: str, c: float)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors inherited from Foo:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)


>>> print(pydoc.render_doc(SubFoo.method, "Help on %s"))
Help on function method in module __main__

method(self, d: float, a: int, b: str, c: float)

>>> print(pydoc.render_doc(Foo, "Help on %s"))
Help on class Foo in module __main__

class Foo(builtins.object)
 |  Foo(bar: int, baz: str)
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self, bar: int, baz: str)
 |      Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
 |  
 |  method(self, a: int, b: str, c: float)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)


>>> print(pydoc.render_doc(Foo.method, "Help on %s"))
Help on function method in module __main__

method(self, a: int, b: str, c: float)
```

---

It is a common pattern to repeat the superclass's arguments in a subclass in Python. You can either mention them explicitly or collect them in `args` and/or `kwargs` if required and distribute them accordingly as @pts mentioned in the comments.

Ideally, to respect the [Liskov substitution principle (LSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) the subclass should match the signature of the superclass and any additional argument should be optional. This allows the users to use either class interchangeably.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar: int, baz: str, *args, **kwargs):
        self.bar = bar
        self.baz = baz

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)


class SubFoo(Foo):
    def __init__(self, bar: int, baz: str, qux: float=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(bar, baz, qux, *args, **kwargs)
        self.qux = qux
```

Now we can use either class interchangeably:

```
>>> print(SubFoo(10, "foo"))
{'bar': 10, 'baz': 'foo', 'qux': None}
>>> print(SubFoo(10, "foo", 1.2))
{'bar': 10, 'baz': 'foo', 'qux': 1.2}
>>> print(Foo(10, "foo"))
{'bar': 10, 'baz': 'foo'}
>>> print(Foo(10, "foo", 1.2))
{'bar': 10, 'baz': 'foo'}
```

---

Django does something like this for its [`Field` class and its subclasses](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fbe850106b2e4b85f838219cb9e1df95fba6c164/django/forms/fields.py#L82):

It forces the arguments to be keyword-only to make the instantiation even clearer and the base class `Field` doesn't expect `kwargs` to force users to not pass unexpected fields. Here the subclasses only specify the additional keyword arguments they expect and the rest are collected in `**kwargs` and passed to `Field`.

```
# Simple example of linked Django code

class Field:
    def __init__(self, *, required: bool=False, default: object=None):
        self.required = required
        self.default = default

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)


class TextField(Field):
    def __init__(self, *, max_length: int=None, min_length: int=None, **kwargs):
        self.max_length = max_length
        self.min_length = min_length
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class IntField(Field):
    def __init__(self, *, max_value: int=None, min_value: int=None, **kwargs):
        self.max_value = max_value
        self.min_value = min_value
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Usage:

```
>>> print(TextField(max_length=10, min_length=5))
{'max_length': 10, 'min_length': 5, 'required': False, 'default': None}
>>> print(IntField(max_value=23, min_value=2))
{'max_value': 23, 'min_value': 2, 'required': False, 'default': None}
>>> print(IntField(max_value=23, min_value=2, foo="bar"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'foo'

# All can still be initialized using the arguments expected by `Field`
>>> print(IntField(required=True, default=0))
{'max_value': None, 'min_value': None, 'required': True, 'default': 0}
>>> print(TextField(required=False, default=""))
{'max_length': None, 'min_length': None, 'required': False, 'default': ''}
>>> print(Field(required=False, default=object()))
{'required': False, 'default': <object object at 0x105fe6460>}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed answer the question for REPLs, and from your answer and the other answer, it seems likely that there is nothing like this in Python that would meet the requirements during development, even if some static code analysis approach might figure it out. (like CoPilot does, although that's a wildly different approach from typical static code analysis - more like a really good educated guess)

Answer (score -1):

Although there seems to be no clear the line, I have one idea more pythonic than this:

```
super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And my suggestion:

```
super().__init__(Foo)
```

Following the code is a whole revised script:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, Foo):

        print(self.qux)
        print(self.bar)
        print(self.baz)


class SubFoo(Foo):
    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwarg):
        
        self.qux = arg[0]
        self.bar = arg[1]
        self.baz = arg[2]

        super().__init__(Foo)


sb = SubFoo(123, 888, 'ttt')
```

This is output:

```
123
888
ttt
```

But, in this case, the nature of inheritance might be different to use the concept. So, we must develop a new perspective to use this. (Solution makes another problem.)

Note that as you know, we should consider that MRO affects this order that we write, so we must include `super().__init__(Foo)` after allocating instance variables.